# Invalid types int[int] for array subscript

Tags: c, arrays, error-handling

I am trying to pass a double-dimensional array to a function, but it throws this error all the time. My code is below:

```
void initialize_centroids(int *,int,int);(Initialization)

initialize_centroids(centroid[0],noofcentroids,newnoofvar);(inside my main)

void initialize_centroids(int *carray,int p,int q)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
           carray[i][j]=i;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: 'throws this error all the time'? The first thing you need to do (especially as someone doing a Masters in CS) is understand the difference between compile-time errors -- which are not "thrown", and of course happen "all the time" if you haven't eliminated the error -- and runtime errors.  And of course `int *` is not in any way "a double-dimensional array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to an int (`int*`), but you're trying to use two subscripts. Is it a 2D array?  Then the parameter needs to be a pointer to a pointer to an int: `int**`

```
void initialize_centroids(int**, int, int);

int centroid[][] = ....  // wherever this comes from
initialize_centroids(centroid, noofcentroids, newnoofvar);(inside my main)



void initialize_centroids(int** carray, int p, int q)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
            carray[i][j]=i;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Didn't get you.. So should I initialize in my function as int **.Tried this but I get one more error. cannot convert âint*â to âint**â for argument â1â to âvoid initialize_centroids(int**, int, int)â

Comment: cannot convert int (*)[100] to int** for argument â1â to âvoid initialize_centroids(int**, int, int)

Comment: I don't see any memory allocated for centroid, and you're passing a two-dimensional array to a function expecting a pointer to an array of `int *`'s. I suggest that you test your answer before offering it.

Comment: I just had that in there for the signature. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Don't de-reference `centroid` when passing in.  Doing that will only pass your first row.  Do this:

```
initialize_centroids( centroid, noofcentroids, newnoofvar );
```

Then you need to use the correct type here:

```
void initialize_centroids( int **carray, int p, int q )
```

Your array is presumably an `int**`.  That means it's a pointer to a location in memory that contains an array of `int*` pointers.  Each of those pointers (I assume) references memory that has been allocated one row of your array.

Now, once you obtain one of these pointers by doing `carray[i]` you have selected row `i`.  You now have an `int*` which means it points to an array of `int`.

Finally, `carray[i][j]` selects a specific integer from column `j` on row `i`.

*[edit]*

Theory about what might be going wrong...  You may not be allocating a 2D array in a dynamic sense, or indeed it might be a 1D array and you are supposed to use stride-lengths etc.  Here is a solution that you can use for allocating a 2D array dynamically, and indexing it as `carray[i][j]`.

*Note: Some people have gotten upset at me for this method in the past due to alignment concerns, but I have never had issues.  I think they were just having a grumpy day.  For those who are worried about alignment, it's easy to adjust for that, but is too complicated for this example.*

```
int** allocate_array2d( int rows, int cols )
{
    int i, **arr, *data;
    arr = (int**)malloc( rows * sizeof(int*) + rows*cols*sizeof(int) );
    data = (int*)(arr + rows);
    for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
        rows[i] = data;
        data += cols;
    }
    return arr;
}

void free_array2d( int** arr ) {
    free((void*)arr);
}
```

Now, in your main:

```
int** centroid = allocate_array2d( noofcentroids, newnoofvar );
initialize_centroids( centroid, noofcentroids, newnoofvar );
```

*[more...]*

> Okay.Yes I allocated memory like this centroid[100][100] – Bobby 11
>   mins ago

In that case, you should declare:

```
void initialize_centroids( int carray[100][100], int p, int q )
{
    //...
}
```

No need to use my dynamic array example

Comment: Oh, it appears you have declared the array on the stack and are using it as if it was declared on the heap.  Does the array have fixed-size (*ie* hard-coded) dimensions?  I will post code for dynamic allocation.

Comment: Okay.Yes I allocated memory like this centroid[100][100]

Comment: @Bobby Well in that case, you should declare `initialize_centroids( int carray[100][100], int p, int q )`.  No need to use my dynamic array example.

Comment: Yes, that's because `int centroid[100][100]` is not an array of `int*`.  You must either use my dynamic 2D array example (`allocate_array2d(100,100)`), or pass the array as specified in my previous comment.